# Internationalization in LaTeX

Tags: unicode, languages

I am working on auto report generation but this time iIneed to generate report for different language only. Text could be anything like Chinese, French, Russian. Can LaTeX handle all those text dynamically?

Comment: It is an unclear question. You meant the text is only in one language and then LaTeX must translate it to other languages in question automatically? For the current existing LaTeX packages, no necan translate one language to other ones. Instead, you need to prepare the text for each language in advance. Then LaTeX will processes it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It is too difficult to understand what is being asked here. Perhaps, you can try and add an example illustrating what you'd like to really accomplish and what have you done towards that; also it would be nice if you can tell us what your problem precisely is. Thank you.

Comment: Which languages do you need, that is important. Script systems like Arabic, Burmese, Lao, all kind of Nagari, CJK, ...? In any case, your best chances are currently probably with xelatex or with uplatex/babel.

Comment: Actually i have to generate my report in multiple languages ... So text is already there in multiple language just need to use alphabet of that language to write. How can i implement it?

Comment: So far i found i need to generate my report in 1. Chinese 2. Russian 3. Malay 4. Arabic